# How to reduce the modulus of a set of congruent numbers to some modulus?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms, modular-arithmetic

For example:

$S = $ Set of numbers congruent to $\{0, 2, 4\}$ mod $6$

is the same set as

$S = $ Set of numbers congruent to $\{0\}$ mod $2$

Another example:

$S = $ Set of numbers congruent to $\{0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18\}$ mod $20$

is the same set as

$S = $ Set of numbers congruent to $\{0, 1, 2\}$ mod $4$

How can I make these simplifications without needing to analyze the terms of the sets, how to do it programmatically?

Comment: Yes, but I'm looking for an algorithm to reduce the modulus for any given $A$: possible congruences, and $B$: the modulus, for example, given $A = \{0,1,2,4,5,6,8,9,10,12,13,14,16,17,18\}$  and $B = 20$, what steps should be taken to reduce it? in this case, it is reduced to $A = \{0,1,2\}$ and $B = 4$

Comment: The possible smaller moduli $d$ are factors of the modulus $n=dk\,$ such that their cofactor $k$ divides $|S|$, since each value $\!\bmod d$ coressponds to $k$ values $\!\bmod dk,\,$ e.g. $0\bmod 4\to 0,4,8,12,16\bmod 20$ has $\,k=20/4 = 5\,$ values. So e.g. we can't have $\,d=5\,$ since $|S|=15$ is not a multiple of $20/5 = 4.\ \ $

Answer (score 1):

Bill Dubuque's comment essentially answers this question, so I am posting it as CW. If we wish to reduce $S \bmod n$ to the smallest modulus, then:

- loop over all factors $d$ of $n$ such that $k=n/d$ divides $|S|$, in increasing order:

  - make a set $S'$ of all elements of $S$ that are less than $d$
  - multiply each element of $S'$ by the numbers $1$ up to $k$, forming a new set $S''$
  - if $S''=S$ then $(S \bmod n) = (S' \bmod d)$, otherwise $S$ cannot be reduced mod $d$; keep looping.

This loop is guaranteed to terminate, since it certainly succeeds at $d=n$. And since we loop in increasing order, the first success is the smallest possible.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you provided a set $S$ and then requested an algorithm to reduce your values $\mod n$ for some given $n$. The modulus of $S$ beforehand isn't really that relevant as it only gives us a range which we can iterate over anyway.

Now really the only way to go about this is to just iterate over $S$ and take their values $\mod n$, as its entirely possible the last item you iterate over can be an item with a unique residue $\mod n$. This is just

```
new_set = set()
for x in S:
    new_set.add(x%n)
```

which runs in $\Theta(m)$ if $m$ is the length of $S$

Now your examples showed that if two items were equivalent $\mod n$ in $S$, then its exclusion or inclusion property in $S$ is the same. In your $\mod 20$ example, $3\equiv 19\mod 4$ so both $3,19$ were both not included inside of $S$. Similarly $0\equiv 4\mod 4$ so both were included inside.

You didn't explicitly state that this is a property (all numbers equiv $\mod n$ are the same in $S$), but if you assume this then you only need to check the first $n$ numbers

```
new_set = set()
for i in range(n):
    if i in S:
        new_set.add(i)
```

This algorithm runs in $\Theta(n)$ which is as good as you can get, as you must check every members inclusion.

Comment: I think you misunderstood, in $S = $ Numbers congruent to $\{0,2,4\}$ mod $6$, the set is not $\{0, 2, 4\}$, those are the values that $n$ can be congruent mod $6$, the set is $S$ would be the union of set of the numbers that

$n \equiv 0$ (mod $6$)

$n \equiv 2$ (mod $6$)

$n \equiv 4$ (mod $6$)

which is $\{...,-8, -6, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, ...\}$, and happens to be the same as the numbers such that

$n \equiv 0$ (mod $2$)

Comment: I see, you want to know what the smallest modulus is that can generate your set that you already have